# App Engine 500 error on deployment with SDK 1.7.6

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, deployment

After upgrading the appengine-maven-plugin from 1.7.5 to 1.7.6, trying to deploy my app now consistently fails with

```
$ mvn appengine:update
Beginning server interaction for myapp...
5% Using java7 runtime: false
25% Initiating update.

com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=myapp&version=1.7.6&
500 Internal Server Error
```

If I revert to 1.7.5 it works again, so it may be an issue with the 1.7.6 Maven plugin or SDK. I've tried both enabling and disabling java7 but it makes no difference.

Update: deploying with appcfg.sh works fine, so it must be something with the Maven plugin.

Update #2: running with mvn -X shows the following plugin dependencies:

```
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.7.6:update (default-cli) @ myapp ---
[DEBUG] com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:jar:1.7.6:
...
[DEBUG]    com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:jar:1.7.6:compile
```

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of time by *not* using the latest version which is being considered a test version.

Comment: Where does it say it's a test version? 1.7.6 is the one currently displayed in the [downloads](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Java) page.

Comment: N - OK. Officially it's a stable version, but given the number of bugs raised it is pretty much a test version. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

Comment: Asking the obvious: You replaced your real app_id with `myapp`? (Which should have given a different error.)

Comment: @Dave yes `myapp` is just a placeholder

Comment: Can you paste the results of mvn dependency:tree?  Feel free to redact anything not pertaining to appengine

Comment: @MattStep `mvn dependency:tree` shows project dependencies and  `com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.7.6:compile` is the only relevant one. `mvn -X appengine:update` also shows plugin dependencies - see updated question.

Comment: Interesting, are you specifying any configuration for the plugin?